# A Context free grammar question and how to approach it

Tags: computer-science

I would like to know how to approach a problem like this please, like what steps to consider first? The question is as follows:

what is the language over a,b defined by this CFG

- S ->AS
- S ->1A
- S ->1S
- A ->AA
- A ->0A1
- A ->1A0
- A ->e (blank)

Please teach me how to tackle problems like these. Thanks

Comment: My way is just to derive some examples and see what is possible and what isn't.
In that example you can see that with A's you can derive words which are concatenations of words of the form $\overline{w}w$, now as long as you have the variable S, you can derive strings of 1's between some A's. so i guess the language is concatenations of $(L\{1\}^*)^*L$ where $L=\{w\overline{w}|w\in\{0,1\}^{*}\}$ should prove it thou.